# How can I add a variable that only changes over years in panel data regression model (plm)?

Tags: r, variables, panel-data, plm

I have a panel data of 416 companies (of one country) over 9 `Years`. I only have micro (firms' info) variables as independent in the multiple regression model I created using `plm`. Dependent (outcome) is firm's performance.

I would like to add macro variables such as the inflation rate that only changes over years and remains the same for all companies in the existing model, how this would look in a model? Is there any specificities as tying it to the `Year` variable?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using `match`. Assuming your `inflation` data is a matrix with a *time* column and a *value* column, like this:

```
inflation
#   time   inflation
# 1    1 0.007334147
# 2    2 0.207658973
# 3    3 0.906601408
```

Then just `match` the `time` column of your data set with the `time` column of your `inflation` matrix and subset the latter like so:

```
dat$inflation <- inflation[match(dat$time, inflation$time), "inflation"]
dat
#   unit time           X           y   inflation
# 1    a    1  1.37095845  0.62276512 0.007334147
# 2    b    1 -0.56469817  1.02252057 0.007334147
# 3    c    1  0.36312841  2.46820960 0.007334147
# 4    a    2  0.63286260 -1.07242940 0.207658973
# 5    b    2  0.40426832 -0.07665461 0.207658973
# 6    c    2 -0.10612452 -0.18638359 0.207658973
# 7    a    3  1.51152200  1.39171140 0.906601408
# 8    b    3 -0.09465904 -0.33158244 0.906601408
# 9    c    3  2.01842371 -1.64724356 0.906601408
```

To calculate a unit-FE model just add `inflation` as a covariate.

```
library(plm)
plm(y ~ X + inflation, index=c("unit", "time"), data=dat,
    effect="individual", model="within")
# Model Formula: y ~ X + inflation
# 
# Coefficients:
#         X inflation 
#  -0.33412  -0.88383
```

Check, using LSDV:

```
lm(y ~ 0 + X + inflation + factor(unit), dat)
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ 0 + X + inflation + factor(unit), data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
#             X      inflation  factor(unit)a  factor(unit)b  factor(unit)c  
#       -0.3341        -0.8838         1.0360         0.5068         0.7954
```

---

*Toy data used:*

```
dat <- structure(list(unit = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), time = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), X = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 
0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 
1.51152199743894, -0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704), y = c(0.622765124520913, 
1.02252056852544, 2.46820959836978, -1.07242939863182, -0.0766546052468718, 
-0.1863835944394, 1.39171139678954, -0.331582440622621, -1.64724356396625
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

inflation <- structure(list(time = 1:3, inflation = c(0.00733414688147604, 
0.207658972823992, 0.906601407798007)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: thank you! but I just realised i asked the question in a wrong way

Comment: I hope it is clear now, I've just changed my previous question

Comment: Thank you very much! So I do not need to use something like 'year:inflation', right? And does this apply for twoways effect?

Comment: @SainaV I'm not sure what you're actually attempting to calculate; in a twoways model, besides _unit_ also _time_ is fixed, so inflation will just drop out of the model, doesn't it?

Comment: I have a dummy variable of whether company has BI product or not and I want to estimate how the relationship with performance changes over time. I have micro variables as control variables and wanted to add macro variables as it is used usually in such models (but seems like the significance of them is low anyway, so maybe I do not even add them). As for twoways, I understood that by using that I assume that effect changes over time and over companies, maybe I got it wrong.. (it is my first time using plm)

Comment: @jay.sv I've read more about the twoways and individual effect and you're right. Also i did a test on whether there is a need to do time-fixed model => there is no need, so i shouldn't be using twoways effect. Thank you!

Comment: @SainaV Great! Thanks for informing me!